# What is the difference between view & partial view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-partialview

i am learning mvc. so like to know what is the difference between view & partial view in mvc in terms of functionality.

normal view & partial view both render html in page....so what is the difference and limitation for two?

what are things are accomplish by partial view. please give me few scenario where people need to use partial view.

here is posting two code to load view based on dropdown value change.

```
$(function() {
   $('#myddl').change(function() {
       var url = $(this).data('url');
       var value = $(this).val();
       $('#result').load(url, { value: value })
    });
});

public ActionResult Foo(string value)
{
    SomeModel model = ...
    return PartialView(model);
}

public ActionResult GetView(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            return View("View1", model1);
            break;
        case 2:
            return View("View2", model2);
            break;
        default:
            return View("Default", modelDefault);
    }
}
```

now see one action result return PartialView and another return just view to ajax method. which approach is right? when second approach need to use?

please guide me with knowledge. thanks

Comment: There is already a great answer fo this question - [What is the difference between Partial View and Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730861/what-is-the-difference-between-partial-view-and-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial view kept to use as partial page of the main page(parent page). 

What does mean of partial view? Actually in the main page we will have all the HTML page attributes as below:

html lang="en"

head

title

meta

body

But in partial view we will not have all above attributes.

Find the features of partial page:

1. Partial page will be light wait and get fitted into the any view.

2. This will use as the reusable component.

3. Partial view will be render inside of a View(parent view or page).

For all who coming from ASP.Net background they can understand partial view as user control.

Thanks
Afazal
mdafazal@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

We use partial view to render a specific section of a page, like take an example of Customer. Your Index view of Customer controller will be a normal view while your grid of customers will be a partial view so that when you update or insert a new customer or delete a customer you will just render your partial view which contains grid of customers not the whole index view.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, a partial is used as part of a view and can be shared across multiple views to provide extra functionality for those views. Also, views can be broken down to partials to make editing easier and eliminate redundancy. Hope it helps a little